# Adding osm data to Postgres via Osm2pgsql : duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: openstreetmap, postgresql, osm2pgsql

I'm trying to import osm global world data into a database created in postgreSQL but after a while of processing, I've got this error :

```
Reading in file: E:\planet-latest.osm\planet-latest.osm
Processing: Node(1873580k) Way(0k) Relation(0k)COPY_END for COPY planet_osm_node
s FROM STDIN;
 failed: ERREUR:  la valeur d'une cl├® dupliqu├®e rompt la contrainte unique ┬½
planet_osm_nodes_pkey ┬╗
CONTEXT:  COPY planet_osm_nodes, ligne 1758128898 : ┬½ 2147483647       68830134
7       -16699132       \N ┬╗

Error occurred, cleaning up
```

I read that I have to remove the slim mode but when I do that, another error appeared and tell me I don't have RAM enough.
Have you got any idea?

Comment: I need 50 reputation to comment - but - is there anyway to "bump" a question - I am running into the exact same error and have spent all day trying to import OSM data into a db on Windows using osm2pgsql - thanks!